# EF Core change tracker stores same reference for Current and Original value of complex property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, change-tracking

*SO shows possible duplicates for my question, but I'm not quite sure my case (and actually the question itself) is the same.*

I have an entity with complex property, let's say

```
public class Entity
{
  public Guid Id {get;}
  public ComplexObject Complex {get;}
}

public class ComplexObject
{
  public object CurrentObject{get;}
  public IReadOnlyCollection<object> PendingObjects{get;}
}
```

Just inb4 I have a DDD approach so this limits me to have setters private, so as I got change tracker could use only 'snapshot' strategy for storing/comparing values.\

The issue is here: I'm getting entity, do some operation with `ComplexObject` that modifies it's internal state, then on commiting changes to database EF doesn't sends updated value for `Complex` (as I understood) because Change Tracker returned this property haven't changed.

I've reproduced this on simple example:

1. Read entity from database:
   `DbContext.Entry(entity).Property(x=>x.Complex)...OriginalValue/CurrentValue` returns empty object `{CurrentObject = null, PendingObjects = []}` as it should be in my case.\
2. I do some update operation that should set something into `CurrentObject` (and optionally into `PendingObjects` but it doesn't matter)\
3. Calling `Update` method for repository infrastructure in my code that actually does not much but at least I could intercept this operation and check DbContext.
   `DbContext.Entry(entity).Property(x=>x.Complex)...OriginalValue/CurrentValue` returns here equivalent state like `{CurrentObject = {...}, PendingObjects = []}` however Original one should differ.

I was managed to fix this issue by re-setting value for entity's `Complex` property each time some operation happens (immutable type approach). That lead me to a thought something is wrong with comparing instances. Implementing `IComaprable<>`, `IEquatable<>` or `ICloneable` for `ComplexObject` did nothing for me (perhaps I did something wrong). I also tried to implement `ICloneable` for `Entity` thinking that EF's snapshot taker will try to clone object first, but code haven't entered any of these methods.
In general this fix is quite a workaround I would like to use if any other option will fail.

Also a case googled on SO was to enforce Change Tracker saying that properties A, B, C are changed (`DbContext.Entry(entity).Property(x=>x.Complex).IsModified = true`) well, but this is a shot into my leg.

So the question: is there any docs or article saying how snapshot is being taken from entity by EF and is there a chance to intercept it somehow (or at least try to help it detect changes for properties I know changed).

**P.S.** Not sure if it will help but some updated circumstances. Complex Property field is JSON-serializable into database (Postgres actually). Perhaps there will be a thoughts to use some cool value comparer or whatever component, but in fact I'll compare same referenced instance with same referenced instance, so this seems not a case, or again I'm doing something wrong but not sure what exactly.

**P.P.S.** Okay, let me show you some code in case you want :)

```
internal abstract class AsynchronouslyUpdatedAggregate : AggregateRoot
{
    public ProcessSemaphore ProcessSemaphore { get; }

    ...

    internal void ReleaseLock<TAggregate>(AsynchronousProcess process)
        where TAggregate : AsynchronouslyUpdatedAggregate
    {
        var releaseLock = ProcessSemaphore.TryReleaseLock(process);

        if (!releaseLock.IsLockRemoved)
        {
            throw new AggregateLockedByAnotherProcess(Id, ProcessSemaphore.CurrentProcess?.Id, process.Id);
        }

        ... // nothing interesting there. Semaphore object already modified or exception was thrown and any action doesn't make sense
    }
}

internal class ProcessSemaphore
{
    public Queue<AsynchronousProcess> PendingProcesses { get; }

    public AsynchronousProcess? CurrentProcess { get; private set; }

    ...

    public AggregateUnlockResult TryReleaseLock(AsynchronousProcess process)
    {
        if (CurrentProcess != process)
        {
            return new(false, null); // if this is a case, exception will be thrown, so SaveChanges method will never be called in my case
        }

        PendingProcesses.TryDequeue(out var newProcess);
        CurrentProcess = newProcess; // <-- this is my 100% change

        return new(true, newProcess);
    }
}

internal record AsynchronousProcess(Guid Id);
```

And my test case where ProcessSemaphore property isn't registered as updated:

1. Insert Entity inherited from `AsynchronouslyUpdatedAggregate` having `ProcessSemaphore.CurrentProcess` not null
2. Call API that leads to `TryReleaseLock` method or throws exception
3. ??? PROFIT
4. SaveChanges called under the hood

Comment: `have a DDD approach so this limits me to have setters private,` no it doesn't. DDD has *nothing* to do with how you configure your ORM. As for `could use only 'snapshot' strategy for storing/comparing values` that's what both EF and even ADO.NET's DataTable are doing - both are working disconnected and in both, all pending changes are saved at the same time. `public object CurrentObject{get;}` does violate DDD and OOP in general - instead of using the actual type, or even a generic type, you're saying that this property can hold anything, from integers to movies or other objects

Comment: There's no actual code right now so it's hard to understand what the question is. The snippets show inappropriate use. `DbContext.Entry(entity).Property(x=>x.Complex)` is *definitely* not needed. `SaveChanges` will find all pending changes and store all of them in a single database transaction. The actual values are *only* needed if you get a concurrency exception

Comment: DDD doesn't prescribe how you should use your ORM or data access library at all. It tells you what the *domain entities* should look like, and that the way they're persisted shouldn't spill into the application code itself. ORMs like EF Core help a lot because, when used properly, you get a graph of objects on load, and all changes are persisted atomically on save. The load/save operations are almost transparent. If they aren't, something's wrong

Comment: By mentioning DDD I wanted to say that I can't have entity's structure like `public virtual ComplexObject Complex {get; protected set;}` so EF could register changes via proxy or whatever other way. And I was getting DbEntry from Context while investigating why my database doesn't change even when I 100% know entity's property was updated. I've found that CurrentValue and OriginalValue are always identical (before and after any changes with entity).\
General question is: is there any sort of common interface or any thing I could implement/handle somewhere to help EF detect my changes? :)

Comment: I repeat, DDD says nothing about this or whether you call `SaveChanges` to just save all pending changes. Unless you want to use lazy loading you don't need virtual properties either. A DbContext already is a Unit-of-Work and `SaveChanges` commits all pending changes at once. You're actually *violating* DDD by trying to access the change tracker

Comment: `doesn't change even when I 100% know entity's property was updated` using what code? Are you trying to save only the modified properties perhaps? That works automatically in the "connected" mode but not when attaching detached properties. Perhaps [EF Core Update updates all columns even though only one has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60905605/ef-core-update-updates-all-columns-even-though-only-one-has-changed) would fix the *real* problem?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is correct, your interpretation of DDD is very limiting, I think you potentially mean something else, either your object is immutable, and will not have changes in the same instance, or you must have some public method that allows you to mutate the object. If you are not using standard property setters then you should show your object mutating code and we can help you find a way to register the change. But if you choose not to do things using the standard conventions, do not expect the standard behaviours :)

Comment: Well. Do you really need a real code? :) The simple case is integration test where I inserted entity that has `Entity.Complex.CurrentObject = { some value }` and then try to trigger API that wants to 'nullify' this path. Ofc this is transactional and calls `SaveChanges` under the hood. I have a connected scenario, and from DbContext logs I see that generated SQL updates only aggregate's version field [just a primitive that is always bumped on any movement] but nothing happens to Complex itself

Comment: I've added some code that happens in PPS.

Comment: What does an aggregate root have to do with concurrency and semaphores? The whole point of a Unit-of-Work is that you work for a specific domain task, with a bunch of in-memory data that gets persisted as a whole. This isn't the code we asked (there's no mention of EF at all), but it does show that something really weird is going on.

Comment: Then I didn't get what the code you wanted to check? There are not much EF things happens there, `dbContext.Set<>.SingleOrDefaultAsync()` in the middle of test and `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` somewhere in the end.